# mediatemple - can't send email using codeigniter

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, smtp

I can't send emails using mediatemple in codeigniter.I've checked the email password and smtp host and they are correct.

This is the error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite() [function.fwrite]: send of 12 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
```

This is my code:
I have replaced sxxxxx.gridserver.com with my correct smtp.

```
function _sendEmail($from,$fromname,$to,$subject,$message){
            $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'sxxxxx.gridserver.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'noreply@mywebsite.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'mypass'
        );


        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from($from,$fromname);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit : I have fixed this problem using port 25.**

Comment: If you're connecting via SSL and it's rejecting the connection, it's possible that you don't have SSL installed/enabled/configured correctly on your server. What's your `phpinfo()` look like?

Comment: You might be using it in local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise the the config, see [the codeigniter documentation for the email class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html).

Here is my example which works well...

```
    function send_email($attributes) {

        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'host';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@smtp.com';
        $config['smtp_from_name'] = 'FROM NAME';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'XXX';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';                       

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from($config['smtp_user'], $config['smtp_from_name']);
        $this->email->to($attributes['to']);
        $this->email->cc($attributes['cc']);
        $this->email->bcc($attributes['cc']);
        $this->email->subject($attributes['subject']);

        $this->email->message($attributes['message']);

        if($this->email->send()) {
            return true;        
        } else {
            return false;
        }       

}
```

Comment: The code that I have works with gmail but not with mediatemple.It has something to do with mediatemple.I've tried your code as well but got the same error.

Comment: I guess you need to contact Mediatemplate regarding the error, seems that there is a problem with the smtp host. Perhaps some security feature is in place that prevents you sending mail.

Comment: Fixed the problem.port 456 is only for ssl.I needed to use 25.Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
'smtp_crypto'   => 'ssl',
```

Add this to your config