# Codeigniter contact form email

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to set up a contact form in Codeigniter (I'm running on xampp using Apache and I have a virtual host set up). I have the actual form working but when I try to link it up so that it emails the results I get an error.
I've looked around and tried a few different solutions but I can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Controller:

```
public function contact()
    {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'your name', 'required', array('required'=>"<p class='required'>Please provide %s</p><br>"));
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'your email address', 'required', array('required'=>"<p class='required'>Please provide %s</p><br>"));


            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('templates/headder');
                $this->load->view('contact');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
            else
            {
                $config = array(
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.mydomain.co.uk',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_user' => 'example@mydomain.co.uk',
                    'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
                    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                );

                $message = 'This is a test message... do I work?';

                $this->load->library('email');
                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $this->email->from('ecample@example.co.uk', 'Tester');
                $this->email->to('example@mydomain.co.uk');
                $this->email->subject('New Query');
                $this->email->message($message);
                $this->email->send();

                if($this->email->send()){
                $this->load->view('templates/headder');
                $this->load->view('sent');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
                }
                else
                {
                $this->load->view('templates/headder');
                $this->load->view('contact');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
                }
            }
    }
```

View:

```
 <?php echo form_open('home/contact'); ?>
                <h3><span class='required'>*</span>Name:</h3>
                    <label><input type='text' name='name' value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" maxlength="50" ></label>
                    <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
                <h3>Company:</h3>
                    <label><input type='text' name='company' value="<?php echo set_value('company'); ?>" maxlength="100"></label>
                <h3><span class='required'>*</span>eMail:</h3>
                    <label><input type='email' name='email' value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" maxlength="100"></label>
                    <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
                <input id='submit_button' type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

Error Message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 11 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2131

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\root\CI\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 80
Function: send

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\root\public_html\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT

I have changed the port as suggested on another post however now I am getting the following message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to mail.myemail.co.uk:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1949

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\root\CI\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 68
Function: send

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\root\public_html\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

I tried changing my email address so that it was incorrect just to make sure I hadn't entered my email details wrong and got a different message to say that the connection had been forcibly closed by my host so I don't believe it's anything that simple either.

EDIT
I have set a different email address up and I'm now no longer getting an error however now I'm always getting the "message failed to send" screen and I can't understand why.

EDIT

I have now used print_debugger as suggested in the comments. The result was as followed.

```
220 BLU436-SMTP37.smtp.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 8.0.9200.16384 ready at Mon, 20 Apr 2015 11:25:59 -0700

hello: 250-BLU436-SMTP37.smtp.hotmail.com Hello [90.209.233.150]
250-TURN
250-SIZE 41943040
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8bitmime
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-VRFY
250-TLS
250-STARTTLS
250 OK

Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 20:25:58 +0200
From: "Tester" <myemail@mydomain.co.uk>
Return-Path: <myemail@mydomain.co.uk>
To: myemail@mydomain.co.uk
Subject: =?SIO-8859-1?Q?=4E=65=77=20=51=75=65=72=79?=
Reply-To: "myemail@mydomain.co.uk" <myemail@mydomain.co.uk>
X-Sender: myemail@mydomain.co.uk
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <553544b61c447@mydomain.co.uk>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_553544b61c451"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_553544b61c451
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=SIO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

this is a test


--B_ALT_553544b61c451
Content-Type: text/html; charset=SIO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

this is a test

--B_ALT_553544b61c451--
```

I'm reading this as a MIME problem, is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723404/mediatemple-cant-send-email-using-codeigniter

Comment: have you tried connecting to your URL with telnet... do you get a standard SMTP  prompt?

Comment: I haven't but I have just tried connecting it to a different email address. The result is that I'm no longer getting a error message... But it is routing to the email not sent page.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps email smpt needs ssl:// and if you are using xampp or wamp for testing email you need to configure the mail settings.

```
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.mydomain.co.uk',
```

And Should Be

```
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.mydomain.co.uk';
```

How to setup email on xampp

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho

```
public function contact() {
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->library('email');
$this->load->library('url');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Your Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'your email address', 'required');

// Removed Array From Form Validation


if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

$this->load->view('templates/headder');
$this->load->view('contact');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');

} else {

$config = array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.mydomain.co.uk',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'example@mydomain.co.uk',
'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
'wordwrap' => TRUE,
);

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('ecample@example.co.uk', 'Tester');
$this->email->to('example@mydomain.co.uk');
$this->email->subject('New Query');
$message = 'This is a test message... do I work?';
$this->email->message($message);

if($this->email->send()){
$this->load->view('templates/header'); // Fix spelling Mistake hedder
$this->load->view('sent');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
} else {
$this->load->view('templates/header'); // Fix spelling Mistake hedder
$this->load->view('contact');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your respons. Sadly I had already fixed the port issue. As I'm not using ssl I had to change to a different port and try a different email address. I now no longer get a error but I am getting the message failed to send result and I don't know why.

Comment: @Tessa Try obtaining the error using this line of code after you send the mail.
echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: Here is another link to help learn how to send emails with codeigniter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlNz6GlSjPo

Comment: Hi Harigrovind R, I have updated my origional post with the output from print_debugger am I right in thinking that the problem is with MIME? Any idea how I fix it?

Comment: Hi Wolfgang1983 unfortunately that video doesn't tell me anything that I'm not already doing. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out a number of factors seem to have contributed to this problem. First, I needed to configure some PHP settings, second certain email addresses were blocking the connection (gmail and live mail) so I switched to using an email address on a domain I own which was fine, and finally, just to make things interesting my email account was having technical problems which have now been resolved resulting in about 20 test messages being sent through this morning.

What I did;

In Xampp/PHP/php.ini:

uncomment sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t", the comment out the next instance of sendmail_path.

uncomment extension=php_openssl.dll

Go into Xampp/sendmail/sendmail.ini:

Go to smtp_server and set to your smtp extension (smtp.yourdomain.com) a few lines under this will be a section for username and password. Set this to the username and password for your email account.

I also used the following program within a controller to check that all relevant ports were open:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
    {
    $fp = fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$fp)
        echo "www.google.com -  $errstr   ($errno)<br>\n";
    else
        echo "www.google.com -  ok<br>\n";


    $fp = fsockopen("smtp.yourdomain.com", 465, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$fp)
        echo "smtp.yourdomain.com 465  -  $errstr   ($errno)<br>\n";
    else
        echo "smtp.yourdomain.com 465 -  ok<br>\n";


    $fp = fsockopen("smtp.yourdomain.com", 587, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$fp)
        echo "smtp.yourdomain.com  -  $errstr   ($errno)<br>\n";
    else
        echo "smtp.yourdomain.com -  ok<br>\n";

    $fp = fsockopen("smtp.yourdomain.com", 25, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$fp)
        echo "smtp.yourdomain.com  -  $errstr   ($errno)<br>\n";
    else
        echo "smtp.yourdomain.com 25 -  ok<br>\n";
    }
}
```