# Send Mail With Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

its my controller

```
    $to = "goeboekimutcs@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Goeboek I-Mut";
    $content = "<html><body><p>Test Content</p></body></html>";
    $headers = "From: goeboekimutcs@gmail.com";
    mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
```

it's my php.ini

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"D:\Programs\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the D:\Programs\xampp\mailoutput folder
; sendmail_path="D:\Programs\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

it's my sendmain.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587
auth_username= goeboekimutcs@gmail.com
auth_password= **
```

i open my controller at my browser, after loading, i refresh my gmail but no email come.. sometimes it send but often not send. what happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18180327/3282633

Comment: i try all things and it's still error, sad

Comment: Do you properly gave the port number ? which is given by server ?

Comment: did you enable ssl in php.ini file ?,try with port 465.

Comment: What Operating System Are You Using And Are You Using XAMPP Or WAMP

Comment: Look at this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735568/codeigniter-contact-form-email/29737132#29737132

Comment: i try use port 465 and 587,, both can't
i use windows 7 ultimate, and using XAMPP

Comment: Have you configured your xampp email settings watch tutorial on here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho

Comment: The video you give works like charm
@wolfgang1983 THANK YOU VERY MUCH! YOU SAVE ME

Comment: one more problem @wolfgang1983, i follow the video use mail(......)
but the content i cant use htm tag, how to create content with html tag?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 help mee plz.. now i have problem again, now the email send sometimes, and not send sometimes, what happen? i check the setting, it still the same

Comment: Sorry can not help not much code to go on I would ask new question with your controller etc.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i have edit my code above, need someone help

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use some third party library for sending emails like `PHPMailer` which saves you a lot of headaches. All you need to do is set some initial configurations.

You can get the latest update here and also the usage:

[PHPMailer Github link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)